# No Branching in angular-tree

Tags: css, angularjs, treeview

I am using angular tree . It is working fine but the spacing of nodes when branching is not working...i.e they all are comming in straight line rather than at some distance from each other. Also I am getting this error on browser console.

```
Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 36-36 [?] in expression ['level-' + 1 + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')].
at Error (<anonymous>)
at throwError (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:6309:11)
at lex (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:6272:9)
at parser (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:6466:16)
at http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:7080:29
at compileToFn (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:8973:16)
at Object.Scope.$watch (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:8305:19)
at http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:13541:11
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:4774:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/AngularJS/js/scripts/angular.js:4365:15) <li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng-animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row ng-scope abn-tree-animate-enter-setup">
```

Here is my html file

```
<ul class="nav nav-list abn-tree">
 <li ng-show="header" class="nav-header">{{ header }}</li>
 <li ng-repeat="row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid" ng- animate="'abn-tree-animate'" ng-class="'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ?  ' active':'')" class="abn-tree-row"><a id="{{ row.label }}" ng-  click="user_clicks_branch(row.branch)"><i ng-class="row.tree_icon" ng-click="row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded" class="indented tree-icon"> </i><span   class="indented tree-label">{{ row.label }}</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use my [angular-bootstrap-nav-tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree).

The project has been updated recently to work well under Bootstrap 2 or Bootstrap 3, and also to work with Angular 1.1.5 or Angular 1.2.0 ( and is now MIT licence )

There are 4 working example pages now, using these different versions of Bootstrap and Angular.  Please take another look -- I am sure you will be able to make it work.